# local copy of document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

Why doesn't the following code work?

```
var f = document.getElementsByTagName;
var x = f('div');
```

I get "TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome, "TypeError: Type error" in Safari.  I don't get an error in Firefox, but it doesn't work.  I haven't bothered testing in IE or Opera yet.

Comment: A follow up question should be, why doesn't `document.getElementsByTagName.call(document, 'div')` work in IE?

Comment: Which IE?  It works fine here in IE8.

Comment: @Peter Hansen: IE<8. Before 8 IE hosed methods hanging off of DOM elements (COM objects). Try it: `typeof document.getElementById` returns `"object"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Javascript there is no such thing as a "bound method" (to borrow the term from Python, which I hope you already know or the explanation may need to be longer).  When you grab a reference to "document.getElementsByTagName" you are merely getting a reference to a *function*, not a *method* associated with the document object.  When you call it, "this" is set to the window, not the document, so it doesn't work.

Technically doing this will get you what you want, but as you can probably see it's pointless:

```
var x = f.call(document, 'div')
```

(It's pointless because it's less readable and not as fast as calling document.getElementsByTagName().  Using a closure is similarly pointless.)

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

because in javascript, methods get their `this` from the object on which they're called, and calling a method stored in a separate variable makes that `this` be the global context (or `window`, in browsers).  this should work:

```
var f function ()
{
    return document.getElementsByTagName.apply(
        document
      , arguments
    );
}
var x = f('div');
```

Comment: You can do this without `apply` for two reasons: 1. `getElementsByTagName` receives only *one argument*, 2. Since you are calling the function on the `document` object the context will be *implicitly set*, there is no reason to set it again with apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function f(divName){
  return document.getElementById(divName);
}

var x = f('div');
```

You are trying to call a function, by using the parenthesis. The problem is that 'f', in your code is a variable, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that getElementsByTagName needs to be called on an object. You could say that inside the function definition, it uses `this` to figure out what element to look for the tags in. When you copy the function and then call it, it will be given a new scope, which means that `this` no points to a different object. To call the function on document, try this:

```
var f = document.getElementsByTagName;
var x = f.call(document, "pre");
alert(x[0]);
```