# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, typeerror

When I use `requestAnimationFrame` to do some native supported animation with below code:

```
var support = {
    animationFrame: window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame
};

support.animationFrame(function() {}); //error

support.animationFrame.call(window, function() {}); //right
```

Directly calling the `support.animationFrame` will give...

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

in Chrome. Why?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

In your code you are assigning a native method to a property of custom object.
When you call `support.animationFrame(function () {})` , it is executed in the context of current object (ie support). For the native requestAnimationFrame function to work properly, it must be executed in the context of `window`.

So the correct usage here is  `support.animationFrame.call(window, function() {});`.

The same happens with alert too:

```
var myObj = {
  myAlert : alert //copying native alert to an object
};

myObj.myAlert('this is an alert'); //is illegal
myObj.myAlert.call(window, 'this is an alert'); // executing in context of window
```

Another option is to use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which is part of ES5 standard and available in all modern browsers.

```
var _raf = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

var support = {
   animationFrame: _raf ? _raf.bind(window) : null
};
```

Comment: As of Chrome 33, the second call fails as well with "Illegal invocation". Happy to remove the downvote once the answer is [updated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13278323/1269037)!

Comment: @DanDascalescu: I am using chrome 33 and it is working for me.

Comment: I've just copy-pasted your code and get the Illegal invocation error. [Here's the screencast.](http://imgur.com/oTDsazG)

Comment: You will definitely get illegal invocation error, because the first stamtement `myObj.myAlert('this is an alert');` is illegal. Correct usage is `myObj.myAlert.call(window, 'this is an alert')`. Please read  answers properly and try to understand it.

Comment: If I'm not the only one here getting stuck on trying to get console.log.apply to work in the same way, "this" should be the console, not window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply

Comment: As an alternative to `bind` , it's possible to create an anonymous function/lambda too -- `window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)`) can be replaced with `function(callback){ window.requestAnimationFrame(callback) }`.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use:

```
var obj = {
    alert: alert.bind(window)
};
obj.alert('I´m an alert!!');
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question. I think it should rather be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Also, it is important to bind to appropriate object, e.g. when working with history.replaceState, one should use:

`var realReplaceState = history.replaceState.bind(history);`

Comment: @DeeY: thanks for answering my question! For future people, localStorage.clear requires you to `.bind(localStorage)`, not `.bind(window)`.

Comment: So, in the good ol days it was `let log = console.log` and `let create = document.createElement`, and now it is `let log = console.log.bind(console)` and `let create = document.createElement.bind(document)`. Ok ok ok.

Answer (score 17):

When you execute a method (i.e. function assigned to an object), inside it you can use `this` variable to refer to this object, for example:

```js
var obj = {
  someProperty: true,
  someMethod: function() {
    console.log(this.someProperty);
  }
};
obj.someMethod(); // logs true
```

If you assign a method from one object to another, its `this` variable refers to the new object, for example:

```js
var obj = {
  someProperty: true,
  someMethod: function() {
    console.log(this.someProperty);
  }
};

var anotherObj = {
  someProperty: false,
  someMethod: obj.someMethod
};

anotherObj.someMethod(); // logs false
```

The same thing happens when you assign `requestAnimationFrame` method of `window` to another object. Native functions, such as this, has build-in protection from executing it in other context.

There is a [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function, which allows you to call a function in another context. You just have to pass it (the object which will be used as context) as a first parameter to this method. For example `alert.call({})` gives `TypeError: Illegal invocation`. However, `alert.call(window)` works fine, because now `alert` is executed in its original scope.

If you use `.call()` with your object like that:

```
support.animationFrame.call(window, function() {});
```

it works fine, because `requestAnimationFrame` is executed in scope of `window` instead of your object.

However, using `.call()` every time you want to call this method, isn't very elegant solution. Instead, you can use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It has similar effect to `.call()`, but instead of calling the function, it creates a new function which will always be called in specified context. For example:

```js
window.someProperty = true;
var obj = {
  someProperty: false,
  someMethod: function() {
    console.log(this.someProperty);
  }
};

var someMethodInWindowContext = obj.someMethod.bind(window);
someMethodInWindowContext(); // logs true
```

The only downside of `Function.prototype.bind()` is that it's a part of ECMAScript 5, which [is not supported in IE <= 8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5). Fortunately, there is [a polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

As you probably already figured out, you can use `.bind()` to always execute `requestAnimationFrame` in context of `window`. Your code could look like this:

```
var support = {
    animationFrame: (window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame).bind(window)
};
```

Then you can simply use `support.animationFrame(function() {});`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Quite Common Issue related to binding in JavaScript, and how `this` works —

Suppose I have an function like this `document.write`, if I call it directly, like following, write function is aware of `this` which is referring of `document` object, But in JavaScript there is a things called **Implicity Loss**, or at least thats how we refer it to

```js
document.write("Hello"); // Write is aware of this
```

If I make a alias of the function (its is not copy ), `document.element` to a variable like `x`, you might expect that the function will keep working as it was working, right ?

```js
let x = document.write // x is just a refrence to the write function
```

No, the function `x` is just an alias of `write` function which is a native function in most browsers, which means its implemented by the browser. `x` is not aware of `document` object, so it takes whatever the global scope `this` at time of invoation is to be the `this` for the function.

So if you call function `x` it will give you illigal Invocation error, and to be able to use it you have make `x` aware of `this` , this is what's called `explicit binding` and you can use it using `call` or `bind` like this

```js
x.call(document, "Hello, World!");

// Or you can use bind, which will create a new function

x.bind(document)("Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the proper hint to resolve this issue was proper error handling and logging of promises via XXX.catch() promise method. Then the core issue appeared and I could handle it.