# console.log timestamps in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a quick way of getting Chrome to output timestamps in `console.log` writes (like Firefox does)?

Or is prepending `new Date().getTime()` the only option?

Comment: can you please change the accepted answer? The second most voted one is much simpler.

Comment: Looks like Chrome have changed how to turn this on. See, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61298#issuecomment-431422747

Answer (score 634, accepted):

In Chrome, there is the option in Console Settings (Either press F1 or select Developer Tools -> Console -> Settings [upper-right corner] ) named "Show timestamps" which is exactly what I needed.

I've just found it. No other dirty hacks needed that destroys placeholders and erases place in the code where the messages was logged from.

#### Update for Chrome 68+

The "Show timestamps" setting has been moved to the Preferences pane of the "DevTools settings", found in the upper-right corner of the DevTools drawer:

[image: Show timestamps how-to picture]

Comment: As @Krzysztof Wolny pointed out, this is now built-in to Chrome 35 DevTools. (Yay!) Enable by opening developer tools (e.g. F12 or "Inspect Element"), click on the "gear" to view settings, then check the "Show timestamps" checkbox in the "Console" section. ![Enable timestamps setting in devtools](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bdOCZ.jpg) https://twitter.com/addyosmani#stream-item-tweet-485862365247053824 http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/chrome-35/#timestamps-next-to-console-messages https://codereview.chromium.org/185713007

Comment: Bumped up the rating of this answer for it's exactly what it is nowadays. We wanted Chrome devs to implement this functionality and they finally did it. Leaving my answer merely as a JavaScript exercise and a way to nicely overload builtins. BTW it wasn't destroying placeholders. You are still able to trace back to the point where the function was called I believe. The good use of my snippet is when you need to send logs over the network. Chrome's timestamps are not part of the data set you'd want to send to your remote logging facility.

Comment: Is there a way to use a pattern for the timestamp in Chrome ? I only need the hour and minute.

Comment: **But** is this the timestamp when the thread has ran the line, or is it only the timestamp when the console **receives and starts displaying** the message from that thread?

Comment: On Chrome 68.0.3440.106 I had to open dev tools (F12) > click the three-dot menu in the top right > click settings > select Preferences in the left menu > check show timestamps in the Console section of the settings screen (top right)

Comment: *Unfortunately* `console.log` doesn't seem to work nicely with promises. While my program flows properly sequenced, its `console.log`s always appear messed up, in a different order at each run. Turning on the "Show timestamps" flag doesn't help. Just now I ran a promise in the console at `...18.268` and the first log to appear is timed `...18.243` (time machine??), while the really first one (according to program flow) is timed `...18.266` and appears in the middle.

Comment: 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

This answer once worked for me:
i.e. console "gear icon"; "Show timestamps" checkmark
... but *now I **don't** see "Show timestamps"* in Chrome  70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

So I tried @tekiegirl's suggestion re: Chrome 68:
i.e. open dev tools (F12) > click the three-dot menu in the top right > click settings > select Preferences in the left menu > check show timestamps

... but *I **don't** see "Preferences"* in the left menu of Settings   70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I posted [a question on Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sR-s8c89cAk;context-place=forum/chrome), maybe some security setting is hiding "Show timestamps" From me?

Comment: @TheRedPea I have added my above comment as an answer below, so I could post a screenshot. I checked on Chrome 72.0.3626.121 and this still applies:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124753/2362036

Comment: Thanks @tekiegirl , agree, your answer solves my problem! That is, users of Chrome 68+ must change *DevTools settings* (vs the drawer for *quick Console settings*).in the DevTools settings, "Preferences" tab, "Console" header; youwill find the "Show timestamps" checkbox.

Comment: This should be ON by default!

Comment: There is a similar setting in Opera 68.0.3618.104 version. I solved with this information

Comment: "Guys, we need more gear icons." -- DevTools manager in [Christopher Walken's voice](https://youtu.be/cVsQLlk-T0s)

Comment: Re *"similar setting in Opera"*: Yep. Now also required in Firefox: gear icon (upper right) → *"Show Timestamps"* (second item)

Comment: Why would they _**move**_ it from the Settings pane inside Console, to a Console section in main Settings is just beyond me. I was looking at the Settings pane inside Console and wondered why there's no such option. Didn't think of checking the main Settings. They ought to have just cloned it in both places (linked). They already clone other settings like "Show CORS errors in console", "Eager evaluation" and others, which are linked in both places. Or at least hint in Console that there are more settings in main Settings view. `</rant>`

Answer (score 105):

Try this:

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function(data)
{
    var currentDate = '[' + new Date().toUTCString() + '] ';
    this.logCopy(currentDate, data);
};
```

Or this, in case you want a timestamp:

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function(data)
{
    var timestamp = '[' + Date.now() + '] ';
    this.logCopy(timestamp, data);
};
```

To log **more than one thing** *and* in a nice way (like an object tree representation):

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function()
{
    if (arguments.length)
    {
        var timestamp = '[' + Date.now() + '] ';
        this.logCopy(timestamp, arguments);
    }
};
```

**With a format string** ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTfSy/))

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function()
{
    // Timestamp to prepend
    var timestamp = new Date().toJSON();

    if (arguments.length)
    {
        // True array copy so we can call .splice()
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

        // If there is a format string then... it must
        // be a string
        if (typeof arguments[0] === "string")
        {
            // Prepend timestamp to the (possibly format) string
            args[0] = "%o: " + arguments[0];

            // Insert the timestamp where it has to be
            args.splice(1, 0, timestamp);

            // Log the whole array
            this.logCopy.apply(this, args);
        }
        else
        {
            // "Normal" log
            this.logCopy(timestamp, args);
        }
    }
};
```

Outputs with that:

[image: Sample output]

P.S.: Tested in Chrome only.

P.P.S.: `Array.prototype.slice` is not perfect here for it would be logged as an array of objects rather than a series those of.

Comment: Rewritten the log statement to display objects in Chrome's console in a lovely manner, the previous version was simply showing "[object Object]" or sort of.

Comment: @Neal, of course it doesn't - you have to extend it (; You can do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/nikki-mccavee/5176029)

Comment: This will not work in the general case where the first argument to log is a format string

Comment: @gonvaled deleted my comment as it really didn't make sense - lack of coffee in blood. You're correct, this sample code does not assume  format specifiers. I think, we can go out on a limb here and check for the format string specifiers, based on that produce different outputs.

Comment: how do you get the timestamp colored red?

Comment: @OliverWatkins I believe Chrome highlights strings that way.

Comment: actually we figured out how to customize colors in Chrome : console.info('normal text %c colorful text', 'background: #3366FF; color: #bada55');

Answer (score 34):

I originally added this as a comment, but I wanted to add a screenshot as at least one person could not find the option (or maybe it was not available in their particular version for some reason).

On Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (and now checked in 72.0.3626.121) I had to

- open dev tools (F12)
- click the three-dot menu in the top right
- click settings
- select Preferences in the left menu
- check show timestamps in the Console section of the settings screen

[image: Settings > Preferences > Console > Show timestamps]

Comment: That image is hardly readable. It could at least be [cropped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)).

Answer (score 26):

You can use dev tools profiler.

```
console.time('Timer name');
//do critical time stuff
console.timeEnd('Timer name');
```

"Timer name" must be the same. You can use multiple instances of timer with different names.

Comment: There's also `console.timeStamp('foo')` it just appears as a yellow point in the timeline. It didn't work for me when using names with spaces tho.

Comment: this does not answer the question related to `console.log` or the logging at all

Comment: @AndreasDietrich why not? It does output to the console. More about it on this 2013 blogpost https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/11/22/measuring-execution-times-in-javascript-with-consoletime

Answer (score 10):

Update as of for Chrome 98:

> Settings -> Preferences -> Console -> Show timestamps

[image]

From Chrome 68:

"Show timestamps" moved to settings

The Show timestamps checkbox previously in Console Settings Console Settings has moved to [Settings](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#settings).

[image]

Comment: [@tekiegirl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55124753/1175496) has a screenshot showing where to find the checkbox in the DevTools Settings are ; the screenshot in this answer doesn't show me where to find the "Show timestamps" checkbox.

Answer (score 10):

ES6 solution:

```js
const timestamp = () => `[${new Date().toUTCString()}]`
const log = (...args) => console.log(timestamp(), ...args)
```

where `timestamp()` returns actually formatted timestamp and `log` add a timestamp and propagates all own arguments to `console.log`

Comment: Please elaborate by making it clear to understand for all, what function will do what

Comment: Thanks @YatinKhullar. I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 9):

#### Chrome version 89.0.4389.90 (19.03.2021)

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
2. Find and press the gear wheel icon.

   [image: 1]
3. Check *Show timestamps*.

   [image: 2]

Answer (score 8):

I convert `arguments` to *Array* using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) so that I can `concat` with another *Array* of what I want to add, then pass it into `console.log.apply(console, /*here*/)`;

```
var log = function () {
    return console.log.apply(
        console,
        ['['+new Date().toISOString().slice(11,-5)+']'].concat(
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        )
    );
};
log(['foo']); // [18:13:17] ["foo"]
```

It seems that `arguments` can be [`Array.prototype.unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)ed too, but I don't know if modifying it like this is a good idea/will have other side effects

```
var log = function () {
    Array.prototype.unshift.call(
        arguments,
        '['+new Date().toISOString().slice(11,-5)+']'
    );
    return console.log.apply(console, arguments);
};
log(['foo']); // [18:13:39] ["foo"]
```

Answer (score 7):

`+new Date` and `Date.now()` are alternate ways to get timestamps

Comment: Thanks, +1, but I was hoping that there might be some support for this without having to add code.

Answer (score 5):

Try this also:

```
this.log = console.log.bind( console, '[' + new Date().toUTCString() + ']' );
```

This function puts timestamp, filename and line number as same of built-in  `console.log`.

Comment: ׁThe `log` function created this way freezes a fixed timestamp; you'd have to re-run this every time you want an up-to-date time [= up to time Date ;-].  It is possible to make this a function but you'd have to use it like `mklog()(...)` instead of `log()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Google Chrome browser, you can use the Google Chrome console API:

- console.time: call it at the point in your code where you want to start the timer
- console.timeEnd: call it to stop the timer

The elapsed time between these two calls is displayed in the console.

For detailed information, please see the documentation link: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: To expand on this a little for those like me too lazy to go and look it up. The correct usage is: 

console.time("myMeasure");
[code you want to time]
console.timeEnd("myMeasure");

Comment: this does not answer the question related to console.log or the logging at all

Comment: It was weird that the first sentence was missing [articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) whereas the rest was wasn't. Was the last part copied from somewhere?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (redirects).

Comment: Re *"this does not answer the question related to console.log or the logging at all"*: It may be one of the many completely bogus late answers, with plagiarised content.

Comment: All of this user's answers may be completely bogus and/or plagiarised. Here is [a deleted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15516713).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve line number information (each message pointing to its .log() call, not all pointing to our wrapper), you have to use `.bind()`.  You can prepend an extra timestamp argument via `console.log.bind(console, <timestamp>)` but the problem is you need to re-run this every time to get a function bound with a fresh timestamp.
An awkward way to do that is a function that returns a bound function:

```
function logf() {
  // console.log is native function, has no .bind in some browsers.
  // TODO: fallback to wrapping if .bind doesn't exist...
  return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console, yourTimeFormat());
}
```

which then has to be used with a double call:

```
logf()(object, "message...")
```

BUT we can make the first call implicit by installing a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with getter function:

```
var origLog = console.log;
// TODO: fallbacks if no `defineProperty`...
Object.defineProperty(console, "log", {
  get: function () { 
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(origLog, console, yourTimeFormat()); 
  }
});
```

Now you just call `console.log(...)` and automagically it prepends a timestamp!

```
> console.log(12)
71.919s 12 VM232:2
undefined
> console.log(12)
72.866s 12 VM233:2
undefined
```

You can even achieve this magical behavior with a simple `log()` instead of `console.log()` by doing `Object.defineProperty(window, "log", ...)`.

---

See https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel for a well-done safe console wrapper using `.bind()`, with compatibility fallbacks.

See https://github.com/eligrey/Xccessors for compatibility fallbacks from `defineProperty()` to legacy `__defineGetter__` API.
If neither property API works, you should fallback to a wrapper function that gets a fresh timestamp every time.  (In this case you lose line number info, but timestamps will still show.)

---

Boilerplate: Time formatting the way I like it:

```
var timestampMs = ((window.performance && window.performance.now) ?
                 function() { return window.performance.now(); } :
                 function() { return new Date().getTime(); });
function formatDuration(ms) { return (ms / 1000).toFixed(3) + "s"; }
var t0 = timestampMs();
function yourTimeFormat() { return formatDuration(timestampMs() - t0); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this in most Node.JS apps. It also works in the browser.

```
function log() {
  const now = new Date();
  const currentDate = `[${now.toISOString()}]: `;
  const args = Array.from(arguments);
  args.unshift(currentDate);
  console.log.apply(console, args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I extended the very nice [solution *"with format string"* from JSmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278323/1915920) to also **support**:

- all the other **`console.log` variations (`log`,`debug`,`info`,`warn`,`error`)**
- including **timestamp string flexibility param** (e.g. `09:05:11.518` vs. `2018-06-13T09:05:11.518Z`)
- including **fallback in case `console` or its functions do not exist** in browsers

```
var Utl = {

    consoleFallback : function() {

        if (console == undefined) {
            console = {
                log : function() {},
                debug : function() {},
                info : function() {},
                warn : function() {},
                error : function() {}
            };
        }
        if (console.debug == undefined) { // Internet Explorer workaround
            console.debug = function() {
                console.info('DEBUG: ', arguments);
            }
        }
    },


    /** Based on timestamp logging: from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278323/1915920 */
    consoleWithTimestamps : function(getDateFunc = function() { return new Date().toJSON() }) {

        console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console)
        console.log = function() {
            var timestamp = getDateFunc()
            if (arguments.length) {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
                if (typeof arguments[0] === "string") {
                    args[0] = "%o: " + arguments[0]
                    args.splice(1, 0, timestamp)
                    this.logCopy.apply(this, args)
                } else this.logCopy(timestamp, args)
            }
        }
        console.debugCopy = console.debug.bind(console)
        console.debug = function() {
            var timestamp = getDateFunc()
            if (arguments.length) {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
                if (typeof arguments[0] === "string") {
                    args[0] = "%o: " + arguments[0]
                    args.splice(1, 0, timestamp)
                    this.debugCopy.apply(this, args)
                } else this.debugCopy(timestamp, args)
            }
        }
        console.infoCopy = console.info.bind(console)
        console.info = function() {
            var timestamp = getDateFunc()
            if (arguments.length) {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
                if (typeof arguments[0] === "string") {
                    args[0] = "%o: " + arguments[0]
                    args.splice(1, 0, timestamp)
                    this.infoCopy.apply(this, args)
                } else this.infoCopy(timestamp, args)
            }
        }
        console.warnCopy = console.warn.bind(console)
        console.warn = function() {
            var timestamp = getDateFunc()
            if (arguments.length) {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
                if (typeof arguments[0] === "string") {
                    args[0] = "%o: " + arguments[0]
                    args.splice(1, 0, timestamp)
                    this.warnCopy.apply(this, args)
                } else this.warnCopy(timestamp, args)
            }
        }
        console.errorCopy = console.error.bind(console)
        console.error = function() {
            var timestamp = getDateFunc()
            if (arguments.length) {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
                if (typeof arguments[0] === "string") {
                    args[0] = "%o: " + arguments[0]
                    args.splice(1, 0, timestamp)
                    this.errorCopy.apply(this, args)
                } else this.errorCopy(timestamp, args)
            }
        }
    }
}  // Utl

Utl.consoleFallback()
//Utl.consoleWithTimestamps()  // Defaults to e.g. '2018-06-13T09:05:11.518Z'
Utl.consoleWithTimestamps(function() { return new Date().toJSON().replace(/^.+T(.+)Z.*$/, '$1') }) // E.g., '09:05:11.518'
```

Comment: a **disadvantage** though is that (e.g. in FF 56.0) it **does not show the source location of the log statement, but the one from the `Utl.js` above**. so enabling (on-demand commenting in/out) of the `Utl.consoleWithTimestamps(...)`-override may make sense

Answer (score 1):

This adds a "log" function to the local scope (using `this`) using as many arguments as you want:

```
this.log = function() {
    var args = [];
    args.push('[' + new Date().toUTCString() + '] ');
    //now add all the other arguments that were passed in:
    for (var _i = 0, _len = arguments.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      arg = arguments[_i];
      args.push(arg);
    }

    //pass it all into the "real" log function
    window.console.log.apply(window.console, args); 
}
```

So you can use it:

```
this.log({test: 'log'}, 'monkey', 42);
```

Outputs something like this:

> [Mon, 11 Mar 2013 16:47:49 GMT]  Object {test: "log"} monkey 42

Answer (score 1):

A refinement on the answer by JSmyth:

```
console.logCopy = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = function()
{
    if (arguments.length)
    {
        var timestamp = new Date().toJSON(); // The easiest way I found to get milliseconds in the timestamp
        var args = arguments;
        args[0] = timestamp + ' > ' + arguments[0];
        this.logCopy.apply(this, args);
    }
};
```

This:

- shows timestamps with milliseconds
- assumes a format string as first parameter to `.log`

Comment: This looks almost all good, except that if you `console.log(document, window)`, i.e. without the format string assumption, then you'd get smth. like `2014-02-15T20:02:17.284Z > [object HTMLDocument] 
Window {…}` instead of `document` being represented as an expandable object tree.

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yTfSy/) where I tried to find a solution to the issue you brought up (also updated my answer though prematurely).

Comment: @JSmyth: sure, that is why one of the requirements of my refinement is that the first argument is a format string. To make it flexible, probably a check of the first argument to be a string would be enough.