# How to console data with timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to log some details to browser console. I want to prefix each statement with current data and time.

e.g. `02/02/14 14:37 : some data`

I tried it by creating new Date object. But this turns into creating so many Date objects.

What is the efficient way to do this in javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your current implementaion code?

Comment: Hey - Google it - got http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp - probably not the best site in the world but worth a shot

Comment: What does it have to do with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get datetime in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744299/how-to-get-datetime-in-javascript)

Comment: `(new Date).toISOString()`

Comment: You probably want to automatically [log timestamps in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008120/console-log-timestamps-in-chrome).

Comment: Please see my answer here in similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24260317/209502

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the console.log method into a function

```
function log(txt) {
    console.log(new Date().toString(), txt);
}
```

You can always break it down further to only get the bits and pieces you want.

Then use:

```
log('test');
```

Comment: Get a +1 for writing the code. Simple google would have found the answer