# how to extend console functionality in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently when we write `console.log` it print the `msg`.Can we `extend` the console functionality can we print `current time` with `msg`.I tried like this

```
(function () {
        var old_console =console;
        var newConsole = newconsole;
        function newconsole() {
         var d =new Date();
         old_console.apply(this,arguments);
         return d.getMilliseconds();
        }
    })();
```

but it is not working ..how can we print?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What about `console.log(new Date() + " and message")`?

Comment: @Denny I just give example how I will just send mesg it gives out put with date

Comment: @Halcyon in other words when I type `console.log('abc') .it print `abc` with current time

Comment: [console.image](https://github.com/adriancooney/console.image), you can add functions to the 'console' object.

Comment: `console.log('abc')` works for me

Comment: @user5711656 your code doesn't do anything even remotely close to that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5em99uv7/ see this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log timestamps in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008120/console-log-timestamps-in-chrome)

Comment: best example http://coreymaynard.com/blog/extending-a-javascript-function/ but not able to implement this

Comment: console is an object that gets copied when you assign it to oldConsole and its not a pointer so your function may be changing old_console but not actual console.

Comment: please share fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Create your own logging method rather than console and use that to spit out any format in console.log.
If you want to know timestamp of everything that is happening in console then just enable timestamps from console settings
see [console.log timestamps in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008120/console-log-timestamps-in-chrome)

I have just run [your code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5em99uv7/) with this options enabled in jsfiddle and got this
[image]

When I hover mouse over it, it also shows me date and time.
You can simply see it working with

```js
/*Enable console settings to show timestamps and run this code*/
console.log('abc');
```

You dont need to extent log function to show time. Here is screenshot of new fiddle.
[image: Enable timestamps in console settings. Open console and click on cog icon at top right of console and check timestamps]

Comment: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/extending-a-javascript-function/ using this I tried it

Comment: please share fiddle

Comment: This is your fiddle mate. I just opened console and enabled time stamps in console view. Try it.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/so4v5cwr/ I just append `ddd` in all console but ot working

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome inspector:

```
console.log = function(msg) {
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getMilliseconds() + ' ' + msg;
}

console.log('Hi');
```

Comment: you are overriding the function ..not extending ..:(

Comment: You can now only pass it stringable arguments. That's serious feature degradation.

Comment: here is the best example http://coreymaynard.com/blog/extending-a-javascript-function/

Comment: Nah - this is the best example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278323/351785

Answer (score 0):

```
myLogger = function(msg){
    console.log(new Date()+" " +msg);
}

myLogger('Hi');
```

Simply create a wrapper for console.log which would also include a call `new Date()` responsible for printing the current date as well with the required log message.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to enhance `console.log`, so just address that method - *not* the whole `console` object.

```
(function (console) {
    var old_log = console.log;
    console.log = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        old_log.apply(console, [d].concat(arguments));
        return d.getMilliseconds();
    }
})(window.console);
```

If you want, you can do the same for `console.error()`, `console.info()`, `console.log()`, `console.warn()` etc. Here's an efficient way to do that :

```
(function (console, methods) {
    var old = {};
    methods.forEach(function(method) {
        if(console[method]) {
            old[method] = console[method];
            console[method] = function() {
                var d = new Date();
                old[method].apply(console, [d].concat(arguments));  
                return d.getMilliseconds();
            }
        }
    });
})(window.console, ['error', 'info', 'log', 'warn']);
```

With due consideration, you could probably do similar for [further console methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console).