# requestAnimation frame error

Tags: javascript, html, animation, requestanimationframe

This following is causing an error (FF, Chrome, and ?):

**[JSFiddle recreation](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/fdZWD/)**

```
Engine.prototype.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};
```

And the full context is:

```
var Engine = function(model) {

        this.model = model;
    };

    Engine.prototype.start = function() {
        console.log("ready")
        this.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            console.log("done");
        });
    };

    Engine.prototype.updateUi = function() {

        console.log("update ui");
        this.requestAnimationFrame(this.updateUi);
    };

    Engine.prototype.logRAF = function() {
        console.log(window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame);
        return this;
    };

    Engine.prototype.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };

var engine = new Engine();
engine.logRAF().start();
```

The error is the following in FF - mozRequestAnimationFrame():
`NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object`

The error is the following in Chrome - webkitRequestAnimationFrame():
`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

on the line:

```
this.requestAnimationFrame...
```

The log reads prints out "ready", but not "done"

If I use just a function instead of the native RAF methods, it works ("done" is logged):

**[JSFiddle recreation](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/fdZWD/17/)**

What is going on with the RequestAnimationFrames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're invoking `window`'s function, the *context*(`this`) must be the `window`, not your object( `Engine`'s instance ). [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will help you to resolve that problem:

```
Engine.prototype.requestAnimationFrame = 
        (window.requestAnimationFrame && window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)) ||
        (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame && window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)) ||
        //etc...
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fdZWD/19/)

Comment: You can also use `(window.a || window.b || ...).bind(window)`.

Comment: @pimvdb - assuming one of the "window" RAF function methods is available. If it falls back to the regular function that will through an error.... but yes, there are some shortcuts to be made.

Comment: I don't think it will cause an error - the fallback function doesn't use `this`, so using `.bind` is a no-op for that one.

Comment: @pimvdb undefined.bind(window) is an error http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/RL24r/ - so it just has to be wrapped a little better:

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` should be called in the context of the `window` : `this.requestAnimationFrame.call(window, ...);` as mentioned here: ["Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome)