# Altering the way functions are called in a specific class in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, custom-object, built-in

I'm writing an extension to the javascript context object.

**What I want to achieve:**

In the end, I want to have a function which takes only one argument, canvas. From there on it should extend that canvas element with all kinds of extra functionality that I will write myself.

So basically, turning a canvas into a special canvas as follows:

**Html**

```
<canvas id='normal'></canvas>
<canvas id='special'></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
var normal = document.getElementById("normal"),
    special = document.getElementById("special");

var Extendedctx = function (canvas) {
    // Magic?
}

Extendedctx(special); // Extends the "special" canvas's context (ctx) with lots of extra functionality.

special.getContext('2d').nonBuiltinFunction(); // Should work
normal.getContext('2d').nonBuiltinFunction(); // Should throw an exception
```

The normal canvas however, should stay exactly the same. So, extending the prototype of the builtin ctx-object is not a viable solution.

I'm trying to achieve this by doing the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('testcanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),

    Extendedctx = function (canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.__proto__ = Object.create(this.ctx);
    return this
},  pad = new Extendedctx(canvas);

pad.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

However, the following exception occurs at the last line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

According to the following SO post quote, this should make sense:

> In your code you are assigning a native method to a property of custom object. When you call support.animationFrame(function () {}) , it is executed in the context of current object (ie support). For the native requestAnimationFrame function to work properly, it must be executed in the context of window

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9678166/2302759)

So, to fix that you'll have to call `pad.fillRect.call(pad.ctx, 0, 0, 40, 40);`

Now, this would get annoying and messy really quickly.
What I want to end up with is that:

```
pad.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

would simply work, as well as any other inherited function I might want to use (`eg ctx.arc`)

I really don't know what to do here, I tried googling something along the lines of 'altering functions calls in javascript' and such. No real useful results.

[Here's the jsfiddle in case you need to fiddle around with the js](http://jsfiddle.net/Dzn6F/)

Comment: Please take the time to mark up code correctly and proofread your question.

Comment: Note that `__proto__` is a non-standard (for now) extension supported only by a subset of JavaScript engines.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Does that mean that the post I linked is wrong? It makes _sense_ to me in the sense that I could understand it behaving that way. That doesn't have to mean that it's instantly wrong or right.

I am aware that the \_\_proto__ is non-standard, my goal is to make an app i can use, I could eventually upgrade it to make it work with other browsers than the one I use but that's not my main focus right now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated my post to (hopefully) be clearer about what  I want to achieve. If you have any solutions to this, please consider sharing those :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mixin the properties you want to add on the context.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('testcanvas');

var ExtendedCtx = function(canvas) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.newProp = 20;
    ctx.newMethod = function(){
        return this.newProp/2;
    }
    return ctx;
}

var pad = ExtendedCtx(canvas);

pad.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
console.log(pad.newProp, pad.newMethod(), pad.canvas); // 20, 10, canvas element
```

Comment: This unfortunately does _not_ work the way it should.

Look at [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/GY7Pc/)

It should throw an exception at the `normalpad.newMethod();` line

Your first post (which you deleted) had working code, it didn't behave _exactly_ the same as I proposed it should in the OP post, but it came very near.

Comment: You're extending both the normal and the special canvas contexts. If you do `normalPad = normal.getContext('2d')`, then it will indeed throw the exception you want (http://jsfiddle.net/GY7Pc/1/).

Comment: The first answer was a mess. It worked because of what is left in this answer, but it had a lot of unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 4):

So what you're trying to do is create an object whose prototype is a 2d canvas context.

First, although it won't work, here's the correct way to do that in a general-purpose web page (e.g., one that can't rely on ES5 yet, because of IE8):

```
function getExtendedContext(canvas) {
    var ectx;

    // A one-off constructor function
    function ctor() { }

    // Set the object that will be assigned as a prototype
    // when using that ctor
    ctor.prototype = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Create our object
    ectx = new ctor();

    // Add properties to it
    ectx.nonBuiltinFunction = function() { /* ... */ };

    // Return it
    return ectx;
}

// Usage
var ctx = getExtendedContext(document.getElementById("special"));
ctx.nonBuiltinFunction();
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
```

[With ES5, we could use [`Object.create`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5), but it can't be correctly shimmed on older browsers (and I strongly recommend *not* half-shimming it).]

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iTIwij/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iTIwij/1/edit) *(but again, it doesn't work)*

The problem is that the canvas object and its context objects are DOM objects, not JavaScript objects. DOM objects are what the ECMAScript specification calls "host" objects, and they are not required to act like JavaScript objects. The ECMAScript specification has various notes in it about this (and similarly for host-provided functions, like `alert`).

At least on Chrome, the 2d context object refuses to participate in JavaScript inheritance. When we call `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);` above, we get the exception that you mentioned in your question:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

The reason is that `fillRect` checks to see if `this` (within the call) is a 2d context object, and it isn't — it's the object we created, which has the context as its prototype. So `fillRect` throws a `TypeError`, because `this` isn't a context.

This is unfortunate, because it makes doing what you're trying to do ***much*** harder. To create a true facade for a canvas element, or even just for a 2d context, would require creating a huge amount of code: You'd have to create an object that has all of the methods of a 2d context, and when those methods are called, it calls them on the real 2d context it wraps. Worse, because 2d contexts have writable properties, if you can't count on an ES5 environment, you'd have to set *all* of those properties on the underlying context before making any calls to it. Truly ugly.

So since we can't use inheritance, and using a facade would be really ugly, we need to look at extension: Actually extending the 2d context object itself, rather than using it as a prototype or wrapping it in a facade.

Chrome, at least, tolerates your adding properties to the 2d context object, so you can do this:

```
function getExtendedContext(canvas) {
    var ectx;

    ectx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ectx.nonBuiltinFunction = function() { /* ... */ };

    return ectx;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ufIpuLA/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ufIpuLA/1/edit)

Whether that will work on other browsers is something you'd have to test, because each host is free to do what it wants, including "sealing" host objects.

In your examples, you seemed to want to override the `getContext` on the `HTMLCanvasElement` object itself. Chrome allows you to do that:

```
function extendCanvas(canvas) {
    var realGetContext;

    // Save a reference to the real `getContext` function        
    realGetContext = canvas.getContext;

    // Replace it with our own
    canvas.getContext = function(type) {
        // Call the real one
        var ctx = realGetContext.apply(this, arguments);

        // If the request was for a 2d canvas, extend it
        if (type === "2d") {
            extend2dContext(ctx);
        }

        // Return it
        return ctx;
    };

    return canvas;
}

function extend2dContext(ctx) {
    ctx.nonBuiltinFunction = function() {
        this.fillStyle = "blue";
        this.fillRect(41, 41, 30, 30);
    };

    return ctx;
}

// Usage
var canvas = extendCanvas(document.getElementById("someCanvas"));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.nonBuiltinFunction();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ufIpuLA/2%5C) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ufIpuLA/2/edit)

...but whether other browsers will is, again, something that you'd have to test. If you run into an environment where you can't extend the objects like this, your choices are doing a full facade (which will be really ugly) or falling back on procedural programming (functions you pass the canvas into).