# How to rename native window function so I can remove two lines?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

/*

Is it possible to turn the first block into the second block? I've done something similar with requestAnimationFrame, but because of the dot it does not seem to work here.

*/

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.performance = window.performance || {};

window.performance.now = (function()
{
    return window.performance.now       ||
           window.performance.webkitNow ||
           window.performance.msNow     ||
           window.performance.mozNow    ||
           window.performance.oNow      || function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
})();

var PeRfOrMaNcE = window.performance;

console.log(PeRfOrMaNcE.now());

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var PeRfOrMaNcE = (function()
{
    return window.performance.now       ||
           window.performance.webkitNow ||
           window.performance.msNow     ||
           window.performance.mozNow    ||
           window.performance.oNow      || function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
})();

console.log(PeRfOrMaNcE());
```

Comment: I pity the guy that has to followup this code and remember how you've capitalised `PeRfOrMaNcE` :(

Comment: @Alnitak it looks like he didn't want to confuse it with performance. Calling it something else entirely would have been easier I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Chrome, the `now()` function requires that `this === window.performance`.

You therefore have to use `.call` or .`bind` to invoke it correctly.

This appears to work, although it'll still require that `window.performance` exists, even if it's just initialised to an empty object per your first code attempt:

```
var PeRfOrMaNcE = (function()
{
    return window.performance.now       ||
           window.performance.webkitNow ||
           window.performance.msNow     ||
           window.performance.mozNow    ||
           window.performance.oNow      || function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
})().bind(window.performance);
```

or alternately, avoiding the `.bind` call when `window.performance` doesn't exist:

```
var PeRfOrMaNcE = (function()
{
     var wp = window.performance;
     var now = wp && (wp.now || wp.webkitNow || wp.msNow || wp.mozNow || wp.oNow);

     return now && now.bind(wp) || function() {
         return new Date().getTime();
     }
})();
```

Comment: A more precise explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome/9678166#9678166

Comment: @Alnitak Safari doesn't know window.performance, which is the whole idea.

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe so you'll need to create a dummy `window.performance` too, per your first code block above.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

Concise, but slightly more obfuscated.

```
var PeRfOrMaNcE = function()
{
    var wp = window.performance;
    var v = ['now', 'webkitNow','msNow','mozNow', 'oNow'];
    for (var i in v) {
        if (wp[v[i]]) return wp[v[i]]()
    }
    return (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Comment: Did you run that code? http://jsfiddle.net/P3MCZ/ You are `return`ing inside the `forEach` callback so the `new Date()` version is used regardless of browser used.

Comment: the code is also inefficient because it evaluates the test for which version of `.now` to call _every time the function is invoked_....

Comment: Your code was the first to work. I picked Alnitak's answer because of the self invoking function. I upvoted your answer, but I can not pick 2 answers.