# console.log crashes when assigned to new variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

So this works in firefox and opera, but not in chrome or IE.

```
        window.onload=function(){

            IMS=new Object();
            IMS.putLog=console.log;


            IMS.putLog('IMS Initialized...');

            IMS.putLog('Loading...');
            loadData(userName, passWord);
            IMS.putLog('Loaded...');
        };
```

Fails with illegal invocation

No idea why? any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is when you invoke `IMS.putLog`, the `this` variable for the function is `IMS`; the `console.log` implementation probably is counting on `this` being `console`.

Here's a workaround:

```
IMS.putLog = console.log.bind(console);
```

This will ensure that `this` is `console` when calling the log function.

Unfortunately, this won't work in IE < 9, or maybe other browsers. I know that `bind` doesn't work in PhantomJS, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

See this: ["Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome)

Basically, when you reassign console.log it changes the scope. I'm guess it works in Firefox and Opera just on luck.

A better solution would be:

```
IMS.putLog = function(){
   console.log.apply(console, arguments); //any passed to IMS.putLog will get passed to console.log
};
```

Same result, just called in the correct scope.

Edit: This should work in all browsers that support console.log
Edit2: Brainfart - arguments needs to be applied

Comment: This isn't quite right; `console.log.apply(console, Array.prototype.call(arguments))` might work. If you do `console.log(arguments)`, that will pass the array-like object `arguments` into `console.log` instead of each actual argument.

Comment: Okay, fixed it. `console.log.apply(console,arguments);` works as is. The call to `Array.prototype.call(arguments)` isn't necessary. `apply()` handles `arguments` exactly like an array.

Comment: Nice that arguments finally works well for *something*. This is definitely a better cross-browser solution until `bind` is better supported.

Comment: Haha, yea. I use it all the time.  It's really handy for callbacks.  I'll do something like `callback.apply( (typeof thisArg == "undefined" ? this : thisArg) , arguments );` where `thisArg` is an optional scope param.