# How to resolve Illegal Invocation Type Error in this case?

Tags: javascript, function, return

While solving a programming challenge, I wrote a function which was intended to take a function as an argument and return a function as well. The returned function was meant to execute the argument function (which was passed to first function). The function's code :-

```
function func1(f){
  let func2 = function(){
    if(/*a condition based on a global variable*/){
      f();
    }
  }
  return func2;
}
```

This is currently not working and it raises an `Illegal Invocation Type Error`. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome) question but I don't know how to relate it's answers to my code. So, my questions are :-

- Why isn't my code working?

  What can I do to make it work?

---

**EDIT**

I'm invoking the function like this :-

```
var someFunc = func1(alert);
someFunc("foo");
someFunc("bar");
```

Comment: Exactly how are you *invoking* the function?

Comment: ^. In any cases there are many limitations here, like function arguments and returned value.

Comment: From the edit it appears you need to address binding too.

Comment: @DenysSéguret How?

Comment: check that for a sec https://jsfiddle.net/3masLhgw/ this should work. just add your condition

Comment: @NetaMeta Why putting in a comment what was in an answer 5 minutes before...

Comment: @Densys it wasnt in the answer when i posted it, and its slightly different .... also for String what your trying to do can be accomplished by using .bind() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @DenysSéguret Good for you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle

- the context of the function call
- the arguments
- the returned value

Here's an implementation:

```
function func1(f, context){
  let func2 = function(){
    if( some condition ){
      return f.apply(context, arguments);
    } // there probably should be some "else" behavior...
  }
  return func2;
}
```

With some example uses:

```
var fun = func1(console.log, console);
fun("A", 25); // logs "A", 25
fun = func1(alert);
fun("foo");   // alerts "foo"
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `var` instead of `let`

```
function func1(f){
  var func2 = function(){
    if(/*a condition based on a global variable*/){
      f();
    }
  }
  return func2;
}
```