# console.log throws an error in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

In the excellent book *JavaScript Patterns* by Stoyan Stefanov he gives the following example as a one-off callback:

```
document.addEventListener("click", console.log, false);
```

In Chrome this throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`  In Firefox it throws `TypeError: 'log' called on an object that does not implement interface Console.`  In Safari it throws a generic `TypeError: Type error`.  I'm not sure why.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

console is actually an object and the method log() needs the scope to access this object, e.g.

```
document.addEventListener("click", console.log.bind(console, "test"), false);
```

Comment: This is same thing with my answer. look the question again. Dave kaye trying to use console.log as a parameter "console.log" I think, he dont know about what the functional programming is this? And he is angry with my answer :)

Comment: As you can see, I commented you post- but the given example was poor that's why I added one. Calling console.log inside of a handler is not the same than providing a needed scope for a method.

Comment: Exactly.  And I'm not angry about anything, believe me.

Comment: You arent angry with me? So why did you give down vote to my answer. I was trying to help you with different approach

Comment: Mehmet, I appreciate your response.  Are you sure I'm the one who downvoted your answer?  Are you sure I'm angry with your answer?  As I explained in my comment, the point was not to rewrite the function but to pass console.log() as a callback.  The use of "bind" is much more helpful and tracks with the use of the callback as well as the explanations given in the rest of the chapter. I upvoted Niet's answer and awarded the points to Wolfgang for these exact reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to think what `this` is.

The way you are calling `console.log`, `this` is unset (and unless you're in Strict Mode defaults to `window`). However, the function expects `this` to be `console`, thus giving the "illegal invocation" and "called on an object that does not implement interface Console" - you are literally calling it on nothing (or the Window)

It seems like the code is intended to `console.log` the event data, in which case you should explicitly do so:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {console.log(e);}, false);
```

Note that since it is being called "normally", `this` will be `console` as expected by the browser, and function as intended.

I would however recommend changing it to `console.dir(e)` so that you can actually explore the object data, because I imagine `[object PointerEvent]` isn't very useful.

Comment: This is very close to what I think is the correct answer.

Comment: the best answer: as an example to undestand this even better try: document.addEventListener("click", console.log.bind(console, "test"), false);

Comment: That actually is the correct answer.  Post as answer Wolfgang and I'll give you the points.

Comment: @Dave Kaye Did add it- the short way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `console.log` is a native method and you can't invoke it in a different context. When you pass it around as a callback, you basically assign it to a different context. Same happens if you do the following:

```
var foo = console.log;
foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Here's a [reference SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9678166/2419215).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that O'Reilly books usually have an "errata" page on line, and sure enough there was my answer (page 66).

`document.addEventListener("click", console.log.bind(console), false);`

http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596806767

Answer (score -1):

console.log() is a function! So you can use like this;

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("test log");
}, false);
```

Comment: Except the point is to use console.log as a callback, not fire it in a function.

Comment: You cant use callback like this. When you are calling console.log you must use console.log("bla bla")

Comment: The book is very well written.  I'm pretty sure the author didn't just make this up to confuse people.

Comment: No man it is impossible to write "console.log" as a parameter without callback.  If it used on a book like your code on question. It is wrong too.
Why did you give me "Down Vote" ? Just I am trying to help you!!