# "Illegal Invocation" error on simple script

Tags: javascript

I want to mess around with Speech Recognition API, so I started with the simple page which starts recognition on click on body element. My scripts.js file is:

```
var recognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition();
document.body.addEventListener("click", recognition.start, false);
```

Now when I click anywhere on body element I have the strange error in Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

It refers to first line of my HTML code. My HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this weird error?

Comment: Try `document.body.onclick = recognition.start;`.

Comment: Nope, same error unfortunately.

Comment: try `document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){recognition.start()}, false);`

Comment: Thank you, now it works. But why it works like that, and doesn't work when just passing recognition.start?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre loosing context:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", recognition.start, false);
```

Is equal to:

```
var start = recognition.start;
document.body.addEventListener("click", start, false);
```

So inside of *start*, *this* will refer to *window*, and windows cannot speak. To resolve it, bind:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", recognition.start.bind(recognition), false);
```

or use a function inbetween:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", _=>recognition.start(), false);
```