# Illegal Invocation for nodejs bundled app on a module that exports requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, exception

I'm using nodeJs and webpack to build a client side application.  I've built a module 'animationFrame.js' that exports requestAnimationFrame based on [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/requestanimationframe.shtml) article.

```
exports.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
    || function(f){return setTimeout(f, 1000/60)} // simulate calling code 60 
 
exports.cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame
    || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame
    || function(requestID){clearTimeout(requestID)} //fall back
```

I am using the callback to wait for a generated div to be rendered so that it can be updated based on data returned from a callback method.

```
function mycallback(id, data){
  let sel = $('div.'+id);
  if(!sel.size()){ // wait until element is ready
    animation.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      mycallback(id, data);
    });
  } else {
    if(data == null) $('div.'+id).remove();
    else if(data && data.Title) sel.text(data.Title);
    else sel.text('No Data');
  }
}
```

However I'm getting an Illegal invocation error on the call to `animation.requestAnimationFrame`.  How can I make functions modular to abstract the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Some more searching showed that it was a scoping problem.  I was able to get it working by altering my module using `bind()`.

```
exports.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    || function(f){return setTimeout(f, 1000/60)} // simulate calling code 60 

exports.cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame.bind(window)
    || function(requestID){clearTimeout(requestID)} //fall back
```

["Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome)