# How to modify getters/setters on prototypes?

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter

For functions on prototypes I used to do something like:

```js
var attachShadow = HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow
HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow = function (option) {
    var sh = attachShadow.call(this, option)
    console.log('ShadowDOM Attached!')
    return sh
}
```

On this example, I modified the `attachShadow` method inside the `HTMLElement` prototype to get me notified when a new `shadowDOM` get attached to an element.

Now I wanna do something similar with `ShadowRoot.prototype.adoptedStyleSheets`, but this time `adoptedStyleSheets` is a getter/setter, `var adoptedStyleSheets = HTMLElement.prototype.adoptedStyleSheets` will cause an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

I'm not sure what to do, How to modify getters/setters on prototypes?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677985/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-chrome

Comment: @luekbaja Same error, but the case there is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to retrieve the value inside `adoptedStyleSheets` (which obviously throws an error when called from the prototype) but its property descriptor in order to reuse it in your own `adoptedStyleSheets`:

```js
(function () {
    const oldAdoptedStyleSheetsGetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ShadowRoot.prototype, 'adoptedStyleSheets');

    Object.defineProperty(ShadowRoot.prototype, "adoptedStyleSheets", {
        get: function () {
            console.log('adoptedStyleSheets was accessed!');
            return oldAdoptedStyleSheetsGetter.get.call(this)
        },
    });
})();

customElements.define('web-component', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `Hi I'm a web component`;
    console.log('this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets:', this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets);
  }
});
```

```html
<web-component></web-component>
```

Comment: Prefect, so `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` is what I was looking for!